# Powershell Pester tests stopping after the first assertion failure

Tags: powershell, pester

I am trying to run Pester tests containing multiple `Should` assertions. I want all failing assertions to be collected and reported at the end of the test, just as described here in the [Pester Documentation](https://pester.dev/docs/assertions/should-command#collect-all-should-failures).

Snippet of my test setup:

```
Describe 'GitHelperMethods' {

    BeforeAll{
        # Git setup
        git config --global init.defaultBranch master
        git config --global user.email "testgit@test.com"
        git config --global user.name "testgit"

        # Using local pwd
        $validGitPath = "$PWD/tmp_git_dir/"

        # Initialize git with a file and new commit
        New-Item -Path $validGitPath\test_file.txt -type file -Force
        git init $validGitPath
        git -C $validGitPath add $validGitPath\test_file.txt
        git -C $validGitPath commit -m "initial commit"
        . "$PSScriptRoot/../GitHelperMethods.ps1"
    }

    It 'Has one file change in the working tree' {
        # arrange
        Write-Output "change file contents" > $validGitPath\test_file.txt
        
        # act
        $gitHelper = [GitHelper]::new($validGitPath)
        
        # assert
        $changedFiles = $gitHelper.GetChangedFiles()
        $changedFiles.Length | Should -Be 1000 -Because "Only 1 file was changed and not expecting a value more than 1"
        $changedFiles | Should -Contain "test_fileeeee.txt" 
    }

    ...
}
```

But instead, the behaviour I am seeing is it only displays the first failing assertion error and the remaining assertions are not triggered.
[image: Pester test output]

Using the example provided on [PesterConfigurations documentation](https://pester.dev/docs/commands/Invoke-Pester#example-3), I tried explicitly setting the `Should.ErrorAction = 'Continue'` and then calling `Invoke-Pester` with the custom  Pester configuration like this:

```
$config = [PesterConfiguration]@{
    Run = @{
        Path = 'C:\pester_tests\my_tests.Tests.ps1'
    }
    Should = @{
        ErrorAction = 'Continue'
    }
    Output = @{
        Verbosity = 'Detailed'
    }
}

invoke-Pester -Configuration $config
```

It still fails on the first test assertion and ignores the remaining assertions. Why?

- PSVersion - 7.4.0
- Pester - 5.5.0

Comment: Can you show a sample test suite with which this behavior occurs?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I've extracted one of my tests that show this behaviour. The test fails at the `Should -Be` assertion, but never hits the `Should -Contain` assertion.